# Overlay Icon affects the size of the main window item in Windows opened window list

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar

We have recently added **overlay icons** to an application. So far everything was okay until a user stacked enough windows to have the thumbnail (window preview) swapped for the opened windows list view. Then, this happened.

[image]

*As you can see, the Main window item of the list (**WPF Window**) is taller than other windows.*

This is caused by adding an overlay icon to the application taskbar logo. How could we prevent the main window from resizing?

[image]

*In this case the overlay icon is the envelop*

We have rounded the problem to overlay icons by removing the part of the code that assign it. When no overlay icon are set, the Main window item height is fine.

Here is the resource definition in the **WPF XAML**

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="NewMessageIcon">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <ImageDrawing Rect="0, 0, 16, 16" ImageSource="/SkyMessenger;component/Images/newmessageicon.png" />
         </DrawingImage.Drawing>
 </DrawingImage>
```

And this code is used to set the overlay icon

```
TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay = FindResource("NewMessageIcon") as ImageSource;
```

Is this a normal behavior ? I doubt it, TortoiseSVN uses overlay icons and the main window does not get taller...

What could be causing this? Am I missing something?

Here is a sample project to reproduce the behavior. All you need to do is create a new WPF application and replace the content of MainWindow.xaml with this

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="185" Width="265">

<Window.Resources>
    <!-- <DrawingImage x:Key="Image">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <ImageDrawing Rect="0, 0, 16, 16" ImageSource="/TestWPF;component/Images/imgEnveloppe.png" />
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage> -->
   <DrawingImage x:Key="Image">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 16 16"
                                           RadiusX="3"
                                           RadiusY="3" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>

    </DrawingImage>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Button Margin="37,47,50,59" Click="Button_Click">
        Open another form!
    </Button>
</Grid>

<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo />
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

*This code will create an image at runtime. You can also uncomment the ImageDrawing to test with an image.*

Then replace the content of the MainWindow.xaml.cs with this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay = FindResource("Image") as ImageSource;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

*Click the open another form until windows switched the preview to a window list.*

Comment: 1) Don't call `Window` form (or is it really a winforms `Form`?) 2) Have you tried `TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay = (DrawingImage)FindResource("NewMessageIcon")` (from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.overlay(v=vs.110).aspx)) ?

Comment: @Sinatr What do you mean by don't call Window form?

Comment: I guess you want to do `var window = new MainWindow();` instead of `Form1 form = new Form1();` in button click event handler. Otherwise repro is not compilable. Or what is `Form1` ?

Comment: Form1 is juste an empty form. I did a quick test project in case anyone wanted to test or reproduce. Changing ImageSource to DrawingImage does not help. ImageSource is the abstract class from which DrawingImage, BitmapSource and ImageMetadata inherit. The app is a small chat. The main window is the contact list (in a WPF window). Other window are all chat form (Winform windows)